# Customizing android printing view

Tags: android, android-print-framework

I am using android printing framework. It works correctly, but I want to change some behavior.

Firstly I want to change the layout of activity, that appears, when I invoke `PrintManager print()` method.

Also, it would be nice to print the document without this activity using default printer if it exists. Another word I want to customize process the f printing and use some printing service (mopria alliance for example). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The activity that shows up is for the system app "Print Spooler", you can change certain default print parameters but you cannot change the UI.
Also, the print services are setup to only work with the system, you cannot bind to those services because you need the [BIND_PRINT_SERVICE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_PRINT_SERVICE) permission.